# Using bwa mem and umitools together

Tags: bash, sequencing

I am trying to use bwa mem to align sequence reads to the hg19 reference but my sequences all have a UMI (Unique molecular Identifier). I used umitools like so:

```
umitools trim --end 5 input.fastq NNNNNN > output.fastq
```

This then properly appended my UMI sequence to the name line in the output.fastq file, but then when using bwa mem to align, I get the error that:

```
paired reads have different names: "someTitle:UMI_ATGCTC", "someTitle:UMI_CATTAT"
```

Is there a way to use both bwa mem and umitools together so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this doesn't entirely answer the question, but gets close. umitools does not work for paired end reads as is. What I did to get around this was trim off my UMI sequences (6bp on each side of the reads) and then aligned using the followign code:

```
sed -i~ '2~4s/^.\{6\}//' file
```

The address `2~4` means "start on line 2, repeat each 4 lines".

`s` means replace, `^` matches the line beginning, `.` matches any character, `\{6\}` specifies the length (a "quantifier"). The replacement string is empty (`//`).

`-i~` replaces the file in place, leaving a backup with the `~` appended to the filename.